# Python regex replace digit -1

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to convert a String into proper JSON notation. This string, got some correct indexes (with `[idx]`), and some incorrect indexes (with dot notation `.idx.` with these last ones starting by 1, instead of by 0). Is there anyway to "handle" captured groups using python `re` library or similar?

This is what I have:

```
import re

a = "a.[0].b.1.c"
re.sub(r'\.(\d)\.', r'.[\1].', a)  # Which provides: 'a.[0].b.[1].c'
```

I would like it to give me `'a.[0].b.[0].c'`, but I do not know how can I perform operations on the captured group `$1`. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not replace `.1.` with `.0.`?

Comment: This? Not sure if transferable... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278300/how-to-subtract-1-from-numbers-matched-by-regular-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacer argument of [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can be a function and that function gets passed the match object upon which you can perform operations:

```py
def replacer(mo):
    captured_group = mo.group(1)
    one_subtracted = str(int(captured_group) - 1)
    to_replace = ".[" + one_subtracted + "]."
    return to_replace
```

and using:

```py
>>> re.sub(r"\.(\d)\.", replacer, a)
'a.[0].b.[0].c'
```

Note that `mo` includes all the to-be-replaced string that your pattern matches, so we put the matched `.`s back.

If you want a `lambda`:

```py
re.sub(r"\.(\d)\.", lambda mo: ".[" + str(int(mo.group(1))-1) + "].", a)
```

Comment: You just missed to add the square brackets. Would be ".[" + ... + "].". Appart from that, ir works like a charm! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Mayday Yeah, i was editing that :) Glad to be of help!